# "Iterate through an array using for loops" beginner Java script

Tags: for-loop

I wonder why do i get "You have not seen" as an outcome instead of "You have watched" because the "key-property" "has-watched" is a Boolean set as true? Why do i get false instead?

```
var movies=[
    { Title:"Superman",
      Rating:5,
      hasWatched: true,
    }
    ]

function allThem(movie){
    var result="You have ";
    for(var i=0; i < movie.length ; i++){
        if(movies.hasWatched){result += "watched";}else{result += "not seen";}console.log(result)};} 

allThem(movies) //--I'm calling the function here
 You have not seen //-- This the outcome should be "You have watched" instead of that.
```

Comment: Don't post code as pictures. Add it right to your question.

Comment: Thanks  for the help ,I'm new on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not properly referencing the movie with the `for` loop

The problem is actually in your loop so lets look at that directly

```
function allThem(movie){
  var result="You have ";
  for(var i=0; i < movie.length ; i++){
    if(movies.hasWatched){
      result += "watched";
    }else{
      result += "not seen";
    }
    console.log(result)
  }
}
```

You can see that you're checking the array `movies.hasWatched` property and not actually the movie itself. You need to reference the value in the array with the index you've declared:

```
function allThem(movie){
  var result="You have ";
  for(var i=0; i < movie.length ; i++){
    if(movie[i].hasWatched){ // notice the `[i]` added to this line
      result += "watched";
    }else{
      result += "not seen";
    }
    console.log(result)
  };
}
```

Of course now what happens if you have two movies? You'll output `You have watched` and then `You have watched` + `notseen` for each other movie. We should probably add some identifying information

```
function allThem(movie){
  for(var i=0; i < movie.length ; i++){
    var result="You have "; // moved it in here so that each movie gets a new string
    if(movie[i].hasWatched){
      result += "watched";
    }else{
      result += "not seen";
    }
    result += ' ' + movie[i].Title;
    console.log(result);
  };
}
```

Now you have a different string for each movie!

---

Lets look at another way to do things using more a more updated traversal method, [`Array.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```
var movies=[
  {
    Title:"Superman",
    Rating:5,
    hasWatched: true,
  },
  {
    Title:"Superman 2",
    hasWatched: false,
  }
]

function hasWatched(movie, index, array){
  var out = 'You have '
  if(movie.hasWatched){
    out += 'watched '
  } else {
    out += 'not seen '
  }
  console.log(out + movie.Title)
}

movies.forEach(hasWatched)
// You have watched Superman
// You have not seen Superman 2
```

There are MANY ways to traverse an array including `Array.prototype.forEach()`, `Array.prototype.map()`, `Array.prototype.filter()`, [and even more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Methods) that after some use you'll find yourself hardly ever writing for loops.

Answer (score 0):

i was do in some research you are totally right i have improve much more since the last time  check this up

```
var  movies=[
 {Title: "Superman", Rating: 5, hasWatched: true}1: {Title: "Batman", Rating: 5, 
 hasWatched: false}]                                                                                                       
    Array.prototype.myForEach = function(func){for(var i=0 ;i < this.length ; i++) 
    {func(this[i]);}} 

function movieOf(elem){ var result="You have ";if(elem.hasWatched){ result +="watched ";}else{result +="not seen ";} result += elem.Title;console.log(result)}

movies.myForEach(movieOf)/---This i call the function
 You have watched Superman/--These are  the outputs
 You have not seen Batman
```